# Looping through all the pages in Python web scraping error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a webpage and looping through all the pages within a link. When I am looping through all the pages below code gives many duplicates

```
lst = []
urls = ['https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2019-adding-adaptive-cruise-454662/','https://www.f150forum.com/f118/adaptive-cruise-control-module-300894/']

for url in urls:
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for item in range(1,33):
            response = req.get(f"{url}index{item}/")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
            threadtitle = soup.find('h1',attrs={"class":"threadtitle"})
            for item in soup.findAll('a',attrs={"class":"bigusername"}):
                lst.append([threadtitle.text])
            for div in soup.find_all('div', class_="ism-true"):
                try:
                    div.find('div', class_="panel alt2").extract()                  
                except AttributeError:
                    pass  
                try:
                    div.find('label').extract()
                except AttributeError:
                    pass  
                result = [div.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
                comments.append(result)
```

Modification to the code as below doesnot give duplicates but skips last page of the url

```
comments= []
for url in urls:
    with requests.Session() as req:
        index=1
        while(True):
            response = req.get(url+"index{}/".format(index))
            index=index+1
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
            if 'disabled' in soup.select_one('a#mb_pagenext').attrs['class']:
                break
            posts = soup.find(id = "posts")
            threadtitle = soup.find('h1',attrs={"class":"threadtitle"})
            for item in soup.findAll('a',attrs={"class":"bigusername"}):
                lst.append([threadtitle.text])
            for div in soup.find_all('div', class_="ism-true"):
                try:
                    div.find('div', class_="panel alt2").extract()                  
                except AttributeError:
                    pass  # sometimes there is no 'panel alt2'
                try:
                    div.find('label').extract()
                except AttributeError:
                    pass  # sometimes there is no 'Quote'
                result = [div.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
                comments.append(result)
```

removing " if 'disabled' in soup.select_one('a#mb_pagenext').attrs['class']: break" this code gives infinite loop. How can I loop through pages without getting duplicates

Comment: I will give you my tips to solve pagination: 1) Get last page number. 2)Iterate pages until you dont find element to go next page. Choose what you like more

Comment: I did that in the first part of my code and it gives many duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the order of the if condition to bottom of the loop so that once all the items grab then this will check disabled or not.If you provide at top this will break without capturing the values from last page.

```
comments= []
for url in urls:
    with requests.Session() as req:
        index=1
        while(True):
            response = req.get(url+"index{}/".format(index))
            index=index+1
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

            posts = soup.find(id = "posts")
            threadtitle = soup.find('h1',attrs={"class":"threadtitle"})
            for item in soup.findAll('a',attrs={"class":"bigusername"}):
                lst.append([threadtitle.text])
            for div in soup.find_all('div', class_="ism-true"):
                try:
                    div.find('div', class_="panel alt2").extract()                  
                except AttributeError:
                    pass  # sometimes there is no 'panel alt2'
                try:
                    div.find('label').extract()
                except AttributeError:
                    pass  # sometimes there is no 'Quote'
                result = [div.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
                comments.append(result)

            if 'disabled' in soup.select_one('a#mb_pagenext').attrs['class']:
                break
```